# How do multiple SSIDs provide security?

Tags: wireless-networking

If the ADSL modem router provides multiple wireless SSIDs how does this offer security? Is it possible to have multiple subnets with SSIDs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually the multiple SSID option on a router leads to multiple VLANs, or some other method of separating the traffic between the two networks provided by two SSIDs.  Often this is used to provide a guest network and a non-guest network, and providing some assurance that the guests cannot access the non-guest portion of the network.

Sometimes multiple SSIDs are simply there because the router has multple radios (say one at 5Ghz and one at 2.4Ghz), these are not normally separated and will not be secured from each other.

Comment: I take it that a SSID itself cannot function akin to a VLAN?

Comment: It basically does. Traffic on different SSIDs  passes over the same air but are identified for separation so that devices with different values only see each other if so configured, just as with different VLANs on a cable. However, if any device bridges the two SSIDs, the isolation goes away, just as if you bridged two VLANs.

Comment: It basically does function like a VLAN if it does.  Sorry this can't be more nailed down - an SSID is more like a switchport than a vlan.  It is either part of a VLAN type isolation, or it isn't and is part of the same broadcast domain as the other SSIDs and physical ports.

Comment: @David Schwartz & Paul - So effectively regardless on which SSID the user is on, they are on the same broadcast domain? Is that right?

Comment: @Paul - What you say that `Sometimes multiple SSIDs are simply there because the router has multple radios (say one at 5Ghz and one at 2.4Ghz), these are not normally separated and will not be secured from each other` what do you mean by `these are not normally separated and will not be secured from each other`

Comment: It "depends" - it is down to the implementation in the router as to whether they are in the same broadcast domain or not.  There is no hard and fast rule.

Comment: Dual-Band 802.11n routers operate on both frequencies 5ghz and 2.4ghz.  Usually these radios are bridged together and don't offer any isolation.

Comment: @Paul - So you mean to tell me that any router is capable of segmenting whether the devices communicate on the same broadcast domain?

Comment: @Paul - How do I know whether the radios are bridged?

Comment: This is a matter of implementation - the manual will say whether the ssids can be isolated or not.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: It's exactly like VLANs. They're inherently in different broadcast domains. But if something bridges the two VLANs, then they're the same broadcast domain. If the access point (or some other device) bridges the SSIDs, then they're the same broadcast domain, otherwise not.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of multiple SSIDs is to create distinct wireless networks that can have different security properties. For example, you can create an SSID "HOME" that allows file access and printer sharing and another SSID "GUEST" that only provides Internet access. This keeps your guests from getting access to your machines.

It also allows you to change the encryption key for the "GUEST" network as often as you want (if you gave it to someone you no longer fully trust or just wish to rotate it regularly) without having to change the keys in all your permanent, trusted machines.

Comment: Ah, you got there first.  I'll bump yours.

Comment: @David Schwartz - Thanks. Does it mean I can segment networks into subnets?

Comment: That all depends on the capabilities of the devices. Multiple SSIDs just means there are two distinct wireless networks. What happens with their traffic is up to the devices on them. (If you have a dumb device that just bridges the two SSIDs, then you can't separate traffic at all!)

Answer (score 3):

SSID don't offer security, encryption and authentication do. I'd use the term vlan very carefully for wireless, it should not be confused with a layer 2 wired vlan. Install kismet on your old laptop, and see what you can see.